# Undefined index: b in /path/file.php relating to querystring parameters

Tags: plugin-cforms, query-string, captcha

I am getting errors in the server log for cformsII plugin but don't understand why.

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: b in /var/www/wordpressmu/wp-content/plugins/cforms/cforms-captcha.php on line 12
[Tue Jul 12 15:02:26 2011] [error] [client 172.18.30.81] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: f in /var/www/wordpressmu/wp-content/plugins/cforms/cforms-captcha.php on line 15
[Tue Jul 12 15:02:26 2011] [error] [client 172.18.30.81] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: f1 in /var/www/wordpressmu/wp-content/plugins/cforms/cforms-captcha.php on line 18
[Tue Jul 12 15:02:26 2011] [error] [client 172.18.30.81] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: f2 in /var/www/wordpressmu/wp-content/plugins/cforms/cforms-captcha.php on line 19
[Tue Jul 12 15:02:26 2011] [error] [client 172.18.30.81] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: a1 in /var/www/wordpressmu/wp-content/plugins/cforms/cforms-captcha.php on line 21
[Tue Jul 12 15:02:26 2011] [error] [client 172.18.30.81] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: a2 in /var/www/wordpressmu/wp-content/plugins/cforms/cforms-captcha.php on line 22
[Tue Jul 12 15:02:26 2011] [error] [client 172.18.30.81] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: l in /var/www/wordpressmu/wp-content/plugins/cforms/cforms-captcha.php on line 30
```

> The url to the captcha image is
>   http://mysite/wp-content/plugins/cforms/cforms-captcha.php?ts=3&c1=4&c2=5&ac=abcdefghijkmnpqrstuvwxyz23456789&i=i&w=115&h=25&c=#A6BEA4&l=000066&f=font4.ttf&a1=-20&a2=11&f1=17&f2=19&b=12.gif&rnd=448710

As you can see the variables throwing errors are included in the querystring.

The error is happening against this statement (prep being a function which strips slashes):

```
$im_bg_url      = 'captchabg/' . ( prep($_REQUEST['b'],'1.gif') );
```

Comment: You know that you can (and should) accept answers to your question? That's important for how this site works, please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: You know that you can mark up a question if you find it useful?

Comment: You have asked *six* questions, that have garnered *eleven* answers; not *one* of those answers to any of those questions is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cforms Wordpress Plugin you're using is not properly sanitizing input variables prior use, that's why you get the warnings.

You can either fix the problem your own if you're a coder, or report the issue to the plugin author and discuss if she can fix it.

But from what I googled, there is another version of that plugin, called [cfomsII (Wordpress Plugin)](http://www.deliciousdays.com/cforms-plugin/). It will probably have this issue already fixed so perhaps changing the plugin to the new version is the best suggestion to give.

Comment: That's the version we are using. I have put isset statements in front of all the REQUEST calls.

Comment: Still doesnt answer why I am getting Undefinded index when the querystring parameter is clearly there.

Comment: @JOhnnyBizzle: `$_REQUEST` should have a member for all get parameters. Probably it get's removed somewhere in the program flow? Checking with `isset()` however sounds valid.